# UWP using MVVM and get this error

Tags: c#, json, parsing

So i'm working on a UWP app and i'm using MVVM for parsing a JSON file but sometimes (not always but enough to be worrying) I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

And it always occurs on this line:

```
public BackgroundViewModel SelectedGame
    {
        get { return (_SelectedIndex >= 0) ? _game[_SelectedIndex]: null; }
    }
```

Also the text file i'm parsing is not that big at all:

```
[{"name" : "BrainBox", "image" : "/Images/BrainBox.jpg"},

{   "name" : "DownToATea", 
    "image" : "/Images/DownToATea.jpg"},

{   "name" : "FoalShadow", 
    "image" : "/Images/FoalShadow.png"},

{   "name" : "GoWithTheBuffLow", 
    "image" : "/Images/GoWithTheBuffLow.jpg"},

{   "name" : "SpotTheDifference", 
    "image" : "/Images/SpotTheDifference.png"}

]
```

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code.  Five seconds and you would have had the answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: @Will I was trying that and still couldn't figure the answer so I thought I'd ask rather than break the whole thing apart trying to fix it

Comment: @Jeroen It was solved by another person

Comment: No need to "break the whole thing apart".  You aren't performing bounds checking before indexing into an array.  *Don't do that*.

Comment: @Will well its just both me and my teacher were going through the app and debugger and couldn't see the error so I thought i'd ask some more experienced people. Fresh eyes is the best thing sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the additional information:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: **Index was out of range.** Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

We can guess that it might happen in one of the following scenarios:

1. Classic off by 1 error where `_SelectedIndex` is 1-based
2. `_SelectedIndex` has a default value of 0 even when there is no game to be selected.
3. A game were removed from `_game` and `_SelectedIndex` is still pointing to the last.

Basically, `_SelectedIndex` has gone out of sync with the number of `_game`s. This can be fixed by restricting the index within the boundaries of the array `_game`:

```
return (0 <= _SelectedIndex && _SelectedIndex < _game.Count) ? _game[_SelectedIndex] : null;
```